# Why do I receive syntax error at n in the line If n % i?

Tags: python

My first attempt at python 3.7 code:

```
def prime_chk(n):
        n = int(input('Number to be checked:'))
        print(n)
    for i in Range(n):
        If n % i == 0 & i != n & i != 1:
        print(i)
    else:
        Print('Well done! You have found a prime.')
```

Comment: 1) `If n % i` --> `if n % i`. 2) Indent `print(i)`.

Comment: also, note that python uses the `and` keyword to join conditionals, don't use `&` (which is a bitwise operator), is it much less readable here.

Comment: Also `Range`, `If`, `Print` all should be lower case

Comment: So many mistakes like - Range, If,Print. After corrected syntax error code throws Divide by zero error because range starts from 0.So n%i --> n%0 it throws error.

Comment: `&` is not the logical AND in Python, use `and`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct Code:

```
def prime_chk(upper):
    print("Prime numbers between",0,"and",upper,"are:")
    for num in range(0,upper + 1):
       # prime numbers are greater than 1
       if num > 1:
           for i in range(2,num):
               if (num % i) == 0:
                   break
           else:
               print('Well done! You have found a prime : ',num )

n = int(input('Number to be checked:'))
prime_chk(n)
```